# Can Python make tracked changes

Tags: python-3.x, vba, ms-word

I'm quite new to programming. I recently took an online course in Python 3. I previously wrote an extensive macro in Word VBA that I would like to translate into Python and then develop into an executable program that would open a selected Word document and apply various changes mainly based on find and replace functions.

It's critical that all the changes would be accurately tracked (including formatting changes). Additionally, the software must trigger the acceptance of any existing tracked changes in the document before applying further changes.

Is it possible to do this using Python? Ideally the program should open a Word document, run the specified find/replace functions, save the document as a new file, and then trigger the combine documents function of Word to generate a final file containing all the tracked changes.

I've read through the documentation for the Python Docx module and can't find the answer there or in previous stack overflow questions.

I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the win32com api for python.  This will allow VSTO type control of Office components.

Chapter 7 of Wesly Chun's Core Python Applications Programming (Third edition) will give you a basic grounding.